# Need help in killing window process, using selenium-webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was working with selenium-webdriver, for my scenario I need to kill one window process to perform one of the functionality can I use selenium-webdriver to kill a process?
If yes can anybody help?

Comment: lets say I've a firefox window already opened and I want my test to first close this alrady opened firefox window and then perform some actions by launching new browser... can I do this?

Comment: yes, I think you can do this... please refer the code below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using **WindowsUtils** class

```
    public void killingWindowsProcess() {
        WindowsUtils.tryToKillByName("firefox.exe");
        /* ............. Line of Code......
        ...................................
        ................................... */
    }
```

I think this would solve the purpose.